# Going in the opposite direction with a projection matrix / 3D line from projected 2D point?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a projection matrix $\textbf{P}$ that projects from 3D coordinates to 2D coordinates. Say I have a 3D point $\textbf{X}(x, y, z)$ that gets projected to the 2D point $\textbf{u}(u, v)$.

Thus, we have that $\textbf{u} = \textbf{PX}$ (in homogenous coordinates).

I can see that it should be possible to use the projection matrix to calculate a 3D line but I'm not sure how to write down the mathematical notation. Any help/pointers would great!

[image]

Comment: Why should it be possible to invert this? Consider the projection of a vector onto the $x-y$-plane: $(x,y,z)^T\mapsto (x,y)$. The information on $z$ is lost, and there are many points in 3D which are projected onto the same point in 2D. Or do you have some other kind of inverting in mind?

Comment: I understand that inverting isn't possible. What I meant in the title was - somehow get the results in the opposite direction. I'll edit my title.

Comment: @UtkarshSinha so, you're saying that you want some kind of equation for the line of all points that projected to the same $(u,v)$.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom you're right. I want a 3D line equation corresponding to the point $\textbf{u}(u, v)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\vec x_0 \in \mathbb R^3$ such that $P\vec x_0 = 0$, (i.e. $x_0 \in \ker P$, the kernel or null space of $P$) and any point $\vec x \in \mathbb R^3$ we have that

$$P(\vec x) = P(\vec x) + 0 = P(\vec x) + P(\vec x_0) = P(\vec x +\vec  x_0).$$

This means that given a projected point $\vec u \in \mathbb R^2$, we can find some $\vec x$ such that $\vec u=P(\vec x)$, but this $\vec x$ is only unique up to elements of the kernel of $P$. If you have $\vec x, \vec y$ such that $P(\vec  x) = P(\vec y)$, then their difference is an element of the kernel of $P$.

This gives us a recipe to calculate the points (this is in fact an affine plane in $\mathbb R^3$) which correspond to a given point $u \in \mathbb R^2$:

1. Calculate the kernel (null space) of $P$ by solving $P(\vec x_0) = 0$.
2. Given $\vec u \in \mathbb R^2$, find any single solution $x$ of $P(\vec x) = \vec u$
3. The set you're looking for is $\vec x + \ker P = \{\vec x + \vec x_0:P(\vec x_0)=0\}$.

In essence, $\ker P$ determines the direction of the line and $x$ determines the intercept.

In general, this doesn't need to be a line, but has the (affine) dimension of the kernel of $P$